# Spatstat: Export estimated cluster center coordinate points in fitted ThomasCluster model

Tags: spatstat

If you fit a e.g. Thomas Cluster model (using kppm for example), it will fit a model with X number of clusters.  Is there a way to extract where the center of each of the X clusters are estimated to be? E.g. if the best fit model on a ppp with 500 points has a mean number of 250 points we would expect there to be 2 clusters estimated from the data.  What are the center coordinates of these two clusters?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

`kppm` does not estimate the number of cluster centres or the locations of the cluster centres. It fits a clustered point process model to the point pattern, essentially by matching the K function of the model to the K function of the data. The fitted model only describes the probability distribution of the cluster centres (number and location) and the probability distribution of offspring points relative to their parents.

Estimation/prediction of the actual cluster locations is a much harder task (belonging to the class of missing data problems). You could try the R package `mclust` for this purpose. You can expect it to take a much longer time to compute.

The fitted model parameters obtained from `kppm` could be used to determine the cluster parameters in the `mclust` package to simplify the task.

Comment: Thank you, thats really useful to know.  I could see mclust working very well for normally distributed clusters such as Thomas Clusters, but I am not sure how well it would work for other sorts of clusters, such as VarGamma - do you have any experience of this? Many thanks,